# How to jest.spyOn mock implementation only for the first call then use default implementation?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I would like to use jest.spyOn to mock the implementation of a method only for `the first call`. On 2nd 3rd ...nth call want to call it's actual previous implementation.

I tried the below in ts and it is not working:

```
import handler from '../src/handler';
import * as cRedis from '../src/redis';

jest.spyOn(cRedis, 'rGetAsync');

describe('handle cart quantity validation', () => {
    test('test 1 blabla', async () => {
        (cRedis.rGetAsync as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(
            () =>
                new Promise(resolve =>
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve('{}');
                    }, 1000),
                ),
        );
        const response = await handler();
    });
});
```

the handler function calls the method `rGetAsync` of `cRedis` two times.

just for illustrative example:

handler.ts

```
import { rGetAsync } from './redis';
export default function () {
    const a = await rGetAsync('a');
    const b = await rGetAsync('b');
    console.log(a, b);

}
```

My problem is that the mockedImplementation is used in both calls!

So mockImplementationOnce is not really mocking it once.

I expect that for first call to use the mock implementation and second one the real one.

How can I achieve this with jest?

Comment: Probably the best way would be to use separate test files, presuming they would have different scopes.

Comment: If you decide not to split your test you can take a look at [mockFn.mockReset()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreset)

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code and the following test:

```js
import * as cRedis from '../redis';
import handler from '../handler';

describe('handle cart quantity validation', () => {
  it('test 1 blabla', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(cRedis, 'rGetAsync');
    spy.mockResolvedValueOnce('Not Original')

    await handler();
  });
});
```

My `redis` looks like this:

```js
export const rGetAsync = async () => Promise.resolve('Original implementation');
```

And my output is:

```
 console.log
      Not Original Original implementation
```

So it works properly.

You can check my [post](https://marek-rozmus.medium.com/jest-mock-and-spy-mockclear-vs-mockreset-vs-mockrestore-f52395581950) about clear/reset/restore of spies and mocks.